# Rails: how do I test a helper method that executes a mysql query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm having a method in a helper, that determines whether a user has a specific flag (`enabled`), based on tags and a code, stored in a cookie.

```
def user_enabled?
  Code.joins({tags: :user}).
    where(code: cookies[:user_code]).
    where(users: {enabled: true})
    exists?
end
```

Basically, a tag is associated with a user and a code with a tag.

I'm not really sure how to recreate that in my specs, so that the query executes all the records required. So far I have:

```
it 'returns true when enabled is checked' do
  tag = create(:tag, user: create(:user, enabled: true))
  Code.create(code: 'enabled', tags: [tag])
  cookies[:user_code] = 'enabled'
  expect(user_enabled?).to be_truthy
end
```

But that returns false and I'm not really sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Are you sure `create` is creating records? Try `create!` instead of `create`

Comment: Yes, just made sure of that and it's creating records.

Comment: Try commenting out the `where` conditions in your test 1-by-1 and see if it returns true in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to fix this:

```
Context 'some context'
  let!(:tag) { create(:tag, user: create(:user)) }
  let!(:code) { create(:code, code: 'enabled', tags: [tag]) }

  it 'returns true when enabled is checked' do
    cookies[:user_code] = 'enabled'
    expect(user_enabled?).to be_truthy
  end
end
```